# How to remove the button auto focus from this message box/alert?

Tags: html, vue.js, bootstrap-4, element-ui

I am using element ui message box for alerts. There is no problem with that component in vue in terms of functionality. The concern is that when the alert pops, one of the button has it's focus set automatically.

Please look at the attached image.
[messageBoxButtonFocusIssue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1T09Y.png)

```
MessageBox.confirm('Some user message', 'Warning', {
  confirmButtonText: 'Yes',
  cancelButtonText: 'No',
  showClose: false,
  roundButton: true,
  type: 'warning'
})
```

Is there a way to remove the focus from button 'Yes' when the alert is loaded.

Comment: I suspect your issue here is that you don't like the focus style. That you can probably fix with CSS. It's an accessibility requirement that an element that can take focus be focused when a modal opens.

Comment: Try this : `document.activeElement.blur()`

Answer (score 0):

I also didn't find any solution for this so i have tried the alternative for this below:

```
import swal from sweetalert

swal({ title: 'Warning',
                    text: 'some user message',
                    icon: 'warning',
                    dangerMode: true,
                    buttons: {
                        cancel: {
                            text: 'No',
                            value: null,
                            visible: true,
                            className: 'btn btn-primary',
                            closeModal: true
                        },
                        confirm: {
                            text: 'Yes',
                            value: true,
                            visible: true,
                            className: 'btn btn-secondary',
                            closeModal: true
                        }
                    }
                })
```